# File versions vanish without a trace

Tags: cloud9-ide

We've started work on a project using c9 and are generally very pleased with the level of the product.

However, Over the past few days I have repeatedly experienced the loss of huge amounts of work I did.

For example: I have done work on a file at home, then went in the morning to the office and continued seamlessly - after that, I returned home and experienced the following issue: The preview of the project reflected the work I had done, but the file in the IDE did not. Furthermore, the file history indicated that I indeed worked and saved files, but the history itself did not contain the changes. CLosing the file and re-opening it, or dealing with it in any way caused the site preview to revert as well, and all the work seems to be permanently lost with no trace I ever did it.

This, in addition to being extremely frustrating, also raises a red flag as to the ability of c9 to act as an IDE in any kind of actual production scenario.

If there's anything you can say to me, please do, because I really like the idea, interface and functionality. Otherwise, bye-bye, I'm going back to the old ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, and sorry to hear about these issues you encountered. We did run into a regression this week that could cause such behavior in rare cases. We're releasing a fix for this issue later today! We take such issues very seriously, and we made sure it cannot happen again.

Should you run into problems like this, please contact our Support department at https://support.c9.io directly, as we keep very granular levels of backups and we can easily restore any work you may have lost. StackOverflow is generally better suited for development-related questions.

Hope this helps!

Best,
Ivar